# Non-filling of lines and paragraphs when using docstrings

Tags: fill-paragraph, doc-strings

I am having a problem with docstrings because everything is written as verbatim without paragraph or line filling.  The following for instance puts `Malicious` and `Functionalities` on two separate lines.

```
(defun myfunc
  "For a lengthy list of examples, see:
   [[https://www.gnu.org/proprietary/proprietary.html][Malicious
   Functionalities]]"
(message "myfunc"))
```

Comment: Not addressing your line-wrapping question, but to the best of my knowledge the link format you are trying to use (what I think of as Org format) does not work in docstrings.

Comment: Right.  Does not work in an org buffer also.

Comment: Could one make text fill the line or paragraph?  For instance, when using `insert`?

Comment: Please edit the body of the question to add an example of the behavior that you would like emacs to follow. Right now there isn't a question at all.